# how make a query recursive recipe of recipe ever and ever to infinite

Tags: mariadb

How to perform a recursive inventory search with recipe, and find the lowest 'single' value of the recipe ingredients for user notice, I have the following tables

QkjN6m2snH8
m226f2reF28

```
`estoque`
[0] => [id=>1, nome=>i1, link=>A156, saida=>10, senha=> das165]
[1] => [id=>2, nome=>i2, link=>A160, saida=>3, senha=> das164]
[2] => [id=>3, nome=>i3, link=>A157, saida=>4, senha=> das163]
[3] => [id=>4, nome=>i4, link=>A156, saida=>6, senha=> das162]
[4] => [id=>5, nome=>i5, link=>, saida=>1, senha=> das161]
[4] => [id=>6, nome=>i6, link=>, saida=>1, senha=> das160]
[5] => [id=>7, nome=>i7, link=>A161, saida=>3, senha=> das171]
`receita`
[0] => [id=>1, nome=>p1.1, link=>A156, quantidade=>10, porcao=>0.035]
[1] => [id=>2, nome=>p1.2, link=>A156, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.028]
[2] => [id=>3, nome=>p2.1, link=>A160, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.003]
[3] => [id=>4, nome=>p2.2, link=>A160, quantidade=>6, porcao=>0.025]
[4] => [id=>5, nome=>p2.3, link=>A160, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.029]
[5] => [id=>6, nome=>p3.1, link=>A157, quantidade=>1, porcao=>0.003]103]
[6] => [id=>7, nome=>p3.2, link=>A157, quantidade=>3, porcao=>0.021]
[7] => [id=>8, nome=>p4.1, link=>A156, quantidade=>1, porcao=>0.001]
[8] => [id=>8, nome=>p5.1, link=>A161, quantidade=>1, porcao=>0.010]
[9] => [id=>8, nome=>p5.2, link=>A161, quantidade=>2, porcao=>0.100]
`estoqueMovimento`
[0] => [id=>1, senha=>das164, entrada=> 0.400]
[1] => [id=>2, senha=>das162, entrada=> 0.400]
[2] => [id=>3, senha=>das163, entrada=> 0.400]
[3] => [id=>4, senha=>das161, entrada=> 0.400]
[4] => [id=>5, senha=>das165, entrada=> 0.400]
[5] => [id=>6, senha=>das161, entrada=> 0.400]
[6] => [id=>7, senha=>das160, entrada=> 0.400]
[7] => [id=>8, senha=>das165, entrada=> 0.400]
[8] => [id=>9, senha=>das164, entrada=> 0.400]
[9] => [id=>10, senha=>das171, entrada=> 0.400]
[10] => [id=>11, senha=>das160, entrada=> 0.400]
[11] => [id=>12, senha=>das171, entrada=> 0.400]
```

in case I need to list the stock and check the link to assemble the recipe only for the items that have a link reminding that they may contain recipe within the recipe

final anwser:

```
[0] => [id=>1, nome=>i1, link=>A156, estoque=>1 receita]
[1] => [id=>2, nome=>i2, link=>A160, estoque=>0.33 receita]
[2] => [id=>3, nome=>i3, link=>A157, estoque=>2 receitas]
[3] => [id=>4, nome=>i4, link=>A156, estoque=>999.56 receitas]
[4] => [id=>5, nome=>i5, link=>, estoque=> 0.200]
[5] => [id=>6, nome=>i6, link=>, estoque=> 0.300]
[6] => [id=>7, nome=>i7, link=>A161, estoque=> 1 receita]


SELECT bro.nome,bro.tipo,bro.senha,bro.shanlink,bro.estoqueValido,
                      IF(estoqueValido, 0, bro.minimo) as minimo,
                      IF(estoqueValido, 0, COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida) as estoqueAtual,
                      /*(COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-usr.saida)/(bro.quantidade*bro.porcao) as receita,*/
                      CASE
                        WHEN COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida > bro.minimo THEN 2
                        WHEN COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida <= bro.minimo && COALESCE(SUM(clt.entrada),0)-bro.saida > 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                      END as estoqueStatus
                    FROM estoque as bro
                      LEFT JOIN estoquemovimento as clt ON (bro.senha = clt.senha)
                    GROUP BY bro.senha ORDER BY bro.shanlink DESC, bro.nome ASC
```

i receive ban in brasil thks... qnkuBUAwfe0

Comment: https://portalfacilarquivos.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/ICONHA/imgOrig/%7BADBD2C0C-26AB-2EA1-ACC4-4EA50BA4ABBE%7D.jpg

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/willian.viggiano

Comment: To help you we need to know the version of MySQL or MariaDB you use. Please [edit] youe question to tell us.

Comment: @O.Jones mariadb